# Removing rounded border from table line in ReportLab

Tags: reportlab

I know ReportLab has options for making lines rounded with their 'linejoin' and 'linecap' settings.

For a table, the commands LINEBEFORE or LINEAFTER will put a horizontal line separating two columns on your table.

Is there a way to make this line with no rounded edges? It defaults to rounded edges.

This code will make an example table. How can I make that red vertical line a rectangle with no rounded edges? Or is the solution just adding a thin column between the columns and filling it with red.

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, inch
from reportlab.platypus import Image, Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, Table
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("delete_me.pdf", pagesize=letter)
# container for the 'Flowable' objects
elements = []

styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()


P0 = Paragraph('''
               <b>A pa<font color=red>r</font>a<i>graph</i></b>
               <super><font color=yellow>1</font></super>''',
               styleSheet["BodyText"])
P = Paragraph('''
    <para align=center spaceb=3>The <b>ReportLab Left
    <font color=red>Logo</font></b>
    Image</para>''',
    styleSheet["BodyText"])
data= [['A', 'B', 'C', P, 'D'],
       ['00', '01', '02', P, '04'],
       ['10', '11', '12', P, '14'],
       ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
       ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]

t=Table(data,style=[('LINEBEFORE',(2,1),(2,-2),6,colors.pink)]
)
t._argW[3]=1.5*inch

elements.append(t)
# write the document to disk
doc.build(elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect answer, but making some thin cells to the left and filling them can do the trick

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, inch
from reportlab.platypus import Image, Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, Table
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("delete_me.pdf", pagesize=letter)
# container for the 'Flowable' objects
elements = []

styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()


P0 = Paragraph('''
               <b>A pa<font color=red>r</font>a<i>graph</i></b>
               <super><font color=yellow>1</font></super>''',
               styleSheet["BodyText"])
P = Paragraph('''
    <para align=center spaceb=3>The <b>ReportLab Left
    <font color=red>Logo</font></b>
    Image</para>''',
    styleSheet["BodyText"])
data= [['A', 'B', 'C', P, 'D'],
       ['00', '01', '02', P, '04'],
       ['10', '11', '12', P, '14'],
       ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
       ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]

for i in range(len(data)): # Create slim invisible column
    data[i] = [' '] + data[i]

t=Table(data,style=[
         ('BACKGROUND', (0,1), (0,-2), colors.pink),
        ('LINEBEFORE',(2,1),(2,-2),6,colors.pink)
])
t._argW[3]=1.5*inch

elements.append(t)
# write the document to disk
doc.build(elements)
```

Of course, you'll have to adjust your column widths too

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default `linecap`, by adding your desired linecap to the `style` argument of the `Table`, it is the sixth argument. This prevents the need for filler columns/rows.

```
t=Table(data,style=[('LINEBEFORE',(2,1),(2,-2),6,colors.pink,'squared')]
```

The options for `linecap` are defined as

```
LINECAPS={None: None, 'butt':0,'round':1,'projecting':2,'squared':2}
```